# After upgrading to GHC7, all programs suddenly fail saying "Most RTS options are disabled. Link with -rtsopts to enable them."

Tags: security, haskell, ghc

Haskell tools compiled in the upgraded environment fail with this message, regardless of command line parameters.

Comment: Having flag decoding forbidden as the default is a misfeature, IMO.  People who want the security can ask for it rather than v.v.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it turns out, RTS options can pose a [security issue](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3910), so they can be disabled in GHC7. Then, when a RTS option is passed to such a program, it fails.

The problem was that I had GHCRTS environment variable set, which is added to RTS options of all Haskell programs. Clearing this environment variable solved the issue.