# How to protect against GHC7 compiled programs taking all memory?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, ghc

When playing with various algorithms in Haskell it often happens to me that I create a program with a memory leak, as it often happens with lazy evaluation. The program taking all the memory isn't really fun, I often have difficulty killing it if I realize it too late.

When using GHC6 I simply had `export GHCRTS='-M384m'` in my `.bashrc`. But in GHC7 they added a [security measure](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3910) that unless a program is compiled with `-rtsopts`, it simply fails when it is given any RTS option either on a command line argument or in `GHCRTS`. Unfortunately, almost no Haskell programs are compiled with this flag, so setting this variable makes everything to fail (as I discovered in [After upgrading to GHC7, all programs suddenly fail saying "Most RTS options are disabled. Link with -rtsopts to enable them."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12133000/1333025)).

Any ideas how to make any use of `GHCRTS` with GHC7, or another convenient way how to prevent my programs taking all memory?

Comment: There are of course solutions independent of Haskell, just limiting the memory usage of particular processes. Is this a Linux? — But why don't you just use `-rtsopts` for a program you know to be memory-critical?

Comment: @leftaroundabout What he's saying is that he likes to turn on the `-M384M` option by default for his own programs using the `GHCRTS` environment variable, but now he can't do it because other Haskell tools (such as, perhaps, `cabal-dev`) will fail when given an `RTS` parameter.

Comment: On Linux you can use `ulimit -m` to limit the amount of memory processes started from a shell can take. Other *nixes probably have some variation on the `ulimit` switches they accept.

Comment: @ninjalj: sure `-m` does the trick? I always use `-v`. But I don't really understand that *nix slang or what it is, "maximum resident set size"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile your own programs with `-with-rtsopts=-M384m` to set RTS options at compile time (once and for all). You could also set up a "blacklist" of programs that shouldn't be run with `GHCRTS` in your `.bashrc`; perhaps something like

```
for i in foo bar baz
do
    alias $i="GHCRTS= $i"
done
```